# Dimensions of matrices in $(\mathbf{B}^T(\mathbf{G}^T\mathbf{G})^{-1} \mathbf{B})^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to implement an algorithm from a paper on streamline tracing on a control volume finite element mesh (Painter et al, 2012). One of the equations includes this expression:

$(\mathbf{B}^T(\mathbf{G}^T\mathbf{G})^{-1} \mathbf{B})^{-1}$

where $\mathbf{G}$ is a $n \times d$ matrix with $n>d$ and $\mathbf{B}$ is a $n^b \times d$ matrix, with $n^b<d$.

From my understanding, $(\mathbf{G}^T\mathbf{G})^{-1}$ is a $d\times d$ matrix, and therefore the above expression doesn't work, since the inner dimensions of $\mathbf{B}^T$ and $(\mathbf{G}^T\mathbf{G})^{-1}$ don't match. Is this just a typo in the paper, and the $^T$ should simply be on the other $\mathbf{B}$, or am I confused about matrix algebra?

---

Painter, S. L., C. W. Gable, and S. Kelkar. 2012. “Pathline Tracing on Fully Unstructured Control-volume Grids.” Computational Geosciences 16 (4) (September 1): 1125–1134. doi:10.1007/s10596-012-9307-1.

Comment: Either $B$ is $d\times n^b$ or the transposition symbol is on the wrong matrix.